# multiple graphs in one fig from different input files

Tags: python-3.x, csv, matplotlib

I do not know understand where is the problem in my script. I have opened three files it draw three files but there are some connection lines among the graph. it seems to me there are continuous line. Can anyone help me about it?

```
inputs = (args.input).split(',')


x, y = [],[]
title = "RMSD"
xlabel = "Time (ns)"
ylabel = "RMSD (nm)"

for input in inputs:
    with open(input) as f:
    for line in f:
        cols = line.split()
        if cols[0][0] == "#":
            pass
        elif cols[0][0] == "@":
            pass
        else: 
              try:
                  if len(cols) == 2:
                           x.append(float(cols[0]))
                           y.append(float(cols[1]))
              except ValueError:
                  pass

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x,y ,'r--', label='%s'%input)
legend = ax1.legend(loc='best', shadow=True)
ax1.set_title(title)  
ax1.set_xlabel(xlabel)  
ax1.set_ylabel(ylabel)
plt.savefig('data.png', dpi=500)
```

Image after running my script:
[image]

Comment: All of the points are in one single array. When plotting the points they will all be connected. (How should matplotlib know at which point not to connect them?) The most systematic approach would be to have one x.y pair of arrays per file and issue one plot command per file.

Comment: Dear Sir, problem is, i dont know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to plot the graph in the loop, one plot command per input file.

```
inputs = (args.input).split(',')

x, y = [],[]
title = "RMSD"
xlabel = "Time (ns)"
ylabel = "RMSD (nm)"

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

for inp in inputs:
    x, y = [],[]
    with open(inp) as f:
        for line in f:
            cols = line.split()
            if cols[0][0] not in ["#","@"]:
                try:
                    if len(cols) == 2:
                        x.append(float(cols[0]))
                        y.append(float(cols[1]))
                except ValueError:
                      pass
    ax1.plot(x,y ,'r--', label='%s'%inp)



legend = ax1.legend(loc='best', shadow=True)
ax1.set_title(title)  
ax1.set_xlabel(xlabel)  
ax1.set_ylabel(ylabel)
plt.savefig('data.png', dpi=500)
```